# How to test firebase dynamic links to redirect to TestFlight for uninstalled app?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Is there any solution to test firebase dynamic links, to redirect to TestFlight for uninstalled apps?

Answer (score 0):

I find solution, no need to go to TestFlight, maybe will help someone!

1. Open the deep link and go to the App Store
2. Download the app
   Don't open downloaded app from App Store, but replace it from Xcode. 
   Go to Xcode, Edit schema, under the ‘Run’ section, click on the ‘Info’ tab.
   There’s a button that says ‘wait for the executable to be launched’. Click it instead of ‘automatically’ option.
3. Run app in device, and lunch by clicking app.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to test deeplinks with debug instances is:

1. Uninstall all app instances before opening a deeplink
2. Open the deeplink and proceed to AppStore/PlayStore but **WITHOUT INSTALLING THE APP**
3. Install the app from the desired source (TestFlight, Xcode, Android Studio...)
4. The app will handle the dynamic link once installed

This is possible because, according to Firebase's [Operating System Integrations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/operating-system-integrations), when you tap on a deeplink Firebase is notified of your request, but it will return you the trigger until your app is opened and handles it, no matter the installation source of the app.